# Eigen::Vector; Initialize Vector with Values of Eigen::Matrix3f in a function, bigger than 4 entries

Tags: c++, function, eigen

im interested in building up a 1x6 Vector, which i want to concatenate with another 1x6 Vector to a 2x6 Matrix. I know it will be a Row Vector, so therefore i thought about initializing a **Eigen::RowVectorXf vec**, but maybe a simple Eigen::VectorXf would be enough, idk.

(Further on, this should be concatenated to an even bigger 2Nx6 Matrix, for SVD-Operations)

My Input is a 3x3 Matrix of type **Eigen::Matrix3f Mat**

I thought of using a function, because i have in total ~20 (number isn't that important) input matrices, for each i do have to build 2 vectors, in this manner ( Yep, this will be a 40x6 Matrix in the end):

Question:

How do i initialize **vec** with entries of **mat**, especially if its not only the entries, but the products of entries, or sums of products of entries.

Example:

```
// Inputvalue Mat, which i have
Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 3> mat = [ 1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];

// Outputvalue vec, which i need
Eigen::RowVectorXf = ( mat(0,0)*mat(1,1), mat(1,2)*mat(2,1)+mat(1,0)*mat(0,1), .... );
```

My inputs of mat(**col,row**) are arbitrary, but i have a pattern for **col,row**, which i want to test, and therefore i want to build up those vectors. I've already done it in MATLAB, but im interested in doing it with Eigen in C++.

```
RowVectorXf build_Vec(Eigen::Matrix3f Mat)
{
Eigen::RowVectorCf vec = ( ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ...;);
return vec;
}
```

Anyone some hints for me? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialAdvancedInitialization.html

I already knew my desired dimensions, so i can build 2 RowVectors a(3) and b(3), and then join them together as its written in the example from this link. 

This does even work with Matrices, f.e. i joined 2 RowVectors3f together to 1 RowVectorXf, and then 2 RowVectorsXf to 1 MatrixXf. :) 

Hopefully this helps also other newbies with Eigen.

Comment: You can answer your own question, instead of writing a comment. Btw: If you know the size of your vector/matrix at compile time, I suggest using `Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 6>` (or with 1 instead of 2), instead of `Eigen::MatrixXf`

Comment: Thank you, i'll try it next time :) 

What about if i knew my size of Eigen::Matrix will be
    MatrixXf Vges = MatrixXf::Zero(2 * views, 2 * views);
and i want to fill this vector with all Rowvectors vec, that i build?

I temporarily stored all built Vectors vec inside of another Vector-structure, called VContainer.

For my minimum of three i solved it doing this:
    Vges << VContainer.at(views-3), VContainer.at(views-2), VContainer.at(views-1);

But as you can see its not dynamic, i just typed in 3 2 1, because i couldn't find a solution doing Matrix initialization iterative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamically filling a big matrix at runtime you can't use the CommaInitializer (without abusing it). Just allocate a matrix large enough and set individual blocks:

```
Matrix<float, Dynamic, 6> Vges(2*views, 6);
for(int i=0; i<views; ++i) {
    Matrix<float, 2, 6> foo;
    foo << 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12; // or combine from two Matrix<float, 1, 6>

    Vges.middleRows<2>(2*i) = foo;
}
```

You may also consider computing `Vges.transpose() * Vges` on-the-fly (i.e., by accumulating `foo.transpose()*foo` into a 6x6 matrix and do a SelfAdjointEigendecomposition instead of a SVD (perhaps use double instead of single precision then).

```
Eigen::Matrix<double, 6, 6> VtV; VtV.setZero();

for(int i=0; i<views; ++i) {
    foo = ...;
    VtV.selfadjointView<Upper>().rankUpdate(foo);
}
```

Comment: I try to follow Zhangs Paper about camera calibration, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/a-flexible-new-technique-for-camera-calibration/, 
where the SVD is done only for receiving the eigenvector, associated with smallest eigenvalue of *Vges*. Those entries are the solution for a so called Bmatrix, which is a combination of (A^-1)^T * A^-1, the only real Matrix I'm interested in. Solved with Choleksy-Decomp.
Maybe your more into this topic than me, because i didn't get the usage of the second method, except that i can see my built vectors in VContainer provide full rank.